# Как настроить дефайнера в mysql?

Tags: mysql, debian, phpmyadmin, mariadb, putty

Видимо для гугла этот запрос не очень корректен и я нашёл лишь слёзы на эту тему
У меня есть вопросы:

1. Кто такой дефанер?
2. Какие ф-ции он выполняет
3. Может кто-то из вас имеет на примете крутую статью на эту тему, поделитесь пожалуйста
4. Как всё-таки настроить дефайнера?
   О окружении: Работаю c удалённым сервером ОС debian 10 с фреймворком ларавел через командную строку putty

Дополнение: у меня автоматически появилась bd mysql и там таблица proc[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мы тоже не в курсе, что это за такой «дефайнера в mysql»... скажу, хоть, где ты сталкнулся с этим термином...

Comment: @Fat-Zer definer - определитель
С помощью него получаются доступы к базам и таблицам...
Допустим без него я не могу сделать дамп базы данных, но как его настроить я вообще без понятия

Comment: Дополнил вопрос скрином
Если нужны ещё дополнения, то сделаю

Comment: ок... судя по скрину, это просто пользователь, определивший процедуру/функцию... изменить его можно [ручным `UPDATE`'ом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206820/change-the-stored-procedure-definer) на встроенной таблице mysql (нужны соответствующие права)... ничего другого конкретного советовать пока не буду т.к. подозреваю, что тут [проблема XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-xy)

Comment: ну вот я в затруднении)
получается в бд mysql есть таблица users туда кидаются все кто был создан через CREATE USER  и есть вот эта таблица proc там только root@localhots(в users он тоже есть)
У всех установленно GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES
В таблице proc также имеются такие поля(скрин в вопросе)

Comment: если кто-то что-то в этом понимает, то очень прошу помочь)

Comment: дык, и в чём проблема то?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, если честно, то не встречелся ранее с этим и вообще хз как его настраивать :с
У меня есть в процедурах бд и она тупо не открывается без пользователя crm после переноса..., я вроде как добавлял его, но всё равно обломался....поэтому вот хотел бы узнать получше про этого дефайнера...